# Sendkeys.Send exception: Keyword "SPACE" is not valid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sendkeys

I have the following code :

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe");
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
SendKeys.Send("{D}{I}{R}{SPACE}{ENTER}");
```

I know that `Space` does not do anything here, but I'm trying to solve another issue so my question is why do I get this exception `Keyword "SPACE" is not valid.`? How can I send `space`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You only need to escape special characters ([list at the page here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx)), the rest, including space, can just be written as is;

```
SendKeys.Send("DIR {ENTER}");
```